# How to deduce third eigenvalue/eigenvector pair of a matrix from first two pairs and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose you have a 3 x 3 matrix 'A' with unknown values whose determinant is known and non - zero. If you know two of its eigenvalues and their corresponding eigenvectors, how can you find the third eigenvalue and eigenvector?

Comment: The product of the three eigenvalues is the determinant.

Comment: I know that, but how do you find its corresponding eigenvector?

Comment: You do not know what the matrix values of 'A' are. You only know its determinant and that it's 3x3. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: There’s no way to determine the missing eigenspace without more information about $A$.

Comment: If the third eigenvalue is different of the first and second, the corresponding eigenvector is orthogonal to the two known. You can find it as a cross product.

Answer (score -1):

Let $A=[a_{i,j}]$. You know $spectrum(A)=\{\lambda,\mu,\nu\}$ and $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^3$ s.t. $Au=\lambda u,Av=\mu v$; that is, (since $u,v$ are known up to a factor) $3+2+2$ independent algebraic relations linking the $9$ unknowns $(a_{i,j})$.

So, you miss 2 relations.

EDIT. That follows is false: "you could conclude if you were given -for example- in addition, an eigenvector of $A^T$".

Indeed, the eigenvector of $A^T$ associated to $\nu$ is orthogonal to the plane $span(u,v)$.

Finally, I think the right question is: "find the eigenvector of $A^T$  associated with the third eigenvalue".